# Display Another Player's Scores

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I made a simple multiplayer quiz game. At the end of the quiz I want to display the scores of both players. Is it possible to get PlayerPrefs value from another player?
I use Photon PUN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes sure it is!

You could send a simple request RPC like e.g.

```c#
// Pass in the actor number of the player you want to get the score from
public void GetScore(int playerId)
{
    // Get the Player by ActorNumber
    var targetPlayer = Player.Get(playerId);
    // Get your own ID so the receiver of the request knows who to answer to
    var ownId = PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber;

    // Call the GetScoreRpc on the target player
    // passing in your own ID so the target player knows who to answer to
    photonView.RPC(nameof(GetScoreRpc), targetPlayer, ownId);
}

[PunRpc]
private void GetScoreRpc(int requesterId)
{
    // Get the requester player via the ActorNumber
    var requester = Player.Get(requesterId);
    // Fetch your score from the player prefab
    // -1 indicates that there was an error e.g. no score exists so far
    // up to you how you deal with that case
    var ownScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score", -1);
    // Get your own ID so the receiver knows who answered him
    var ownId = PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.ActorNumber;

    // Call the OnReceivedPlayerScore on the player who originally sent the request
    photonView.RPC(nameof(OnReceivedPlayerScore),  ownId, ownScore);
}

[PunRpc]
private void OnReceivedPlayerScore(int playerId, int score)
{
    // Get the answering player by ActorNumber
    var player = Player.Get(playerId);

    // Do whatever you want with the information you received e.g.
    if(score < 0)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Could not get score from player \"{player.NickName}\"!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log($"Player \"{player.NickName}\" has a score of {score}!");
    }
}
```